# How to use regexp in assert_selector ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, ruby-test

I have a selector that displays date and time on the page, need to write capybara test to check for just date. How to include regexp in assert_selector?

```
assert_selector("div", text: /"#{DateTime.now.strftime('%a %b %d, %H:%M')}"*/i)
```

It doesn't work as a regular expression. What's the syntax in order to test for partial text or substring using assert_selector in ruby on rails

Comment: Is your Date and time really inside "s on your page?

Comment: Yes, I am displaying current date and time on the header

Comment: Ok - but do you display the `datetime` or `"the datetime"` - your regex is actually checking for the "s

Comment: I am display local and utc datetime for eg[(Mon Jul 06, 16:41:52 GMT-04:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` option does accept a regex to match against text, but it also defaults to partial matching so passing a regex is not normally necessary

```
assert_selector("div", text: DateTime.now.strftime('%a %b %d, %H:%M'))
```

will do a partial match against the text of the elements.

If you really want to use a regex (assuming you didn't actually mean to check for surrounding "s) then you'd want something like

```
assert_selector("div", text: /#{Regexp.escape(DateTime.now.strftime('%a %b %d, %H:%M'))}/i)
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't do a partial matching, it looks for exact text

Comment: @Veda Have you changed the Capybara defaults for text matching (ie. you have set Capybara.exact_text = true)?  If so then do `assert_selector("div", text: DateTime.now.strftime('%a %b %d, %H:%M'), exact_text: false)`

Comment: The :exact option only has an effect on queries using the XPath#is method. Using it with the query "div" has no effect.

Comment: I am displaying local and utc date/time in this format ((Mon Jul 06, 16:41:52 GMT-04:00(local) . (Mon Jul 06, 20:41:52(utc))

What will be the regexp to test this string?

Comment: @veda It's `exact_text` not `exact`